# How to calculate the sum of items in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose i have an array:

```
const items = [
  {
    "amount1": "100",
    "amount2": "50",
    "name": "ruud"
  },
  {
    "amount1": "40",
    "amount2": "60",
    "name": "ted"
  }
]
```

I want to get all amount1 and amount2 props totalled and result in:

```
[
  {
    "amount1": 140,
    "amount2": 110
  }
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const items = [{amount1: 100, amount2: 50}, {amount1: 40, amount2: 60}];

const sums = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([k, v]) => acc[k] = (acc[k] || 0) + v);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(sums);
```

To [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out non-number properties (but keep quoted number strings, as per the updated question):

```js
const items = [{amount1: '100', amount2: '50', name: 'Ruud'}, {amount1: '40', amount2: '60', name: 'Ted'}];

const sums = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  Object.entries(item)
        .filter(([_, v]) => !isNaN(v))
        .forEach(([k, v]) => acc[k] = (acc[k] || 0) + Number(v));
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(sums);
```

Comment: Sorry Robby i forgot to mention there is a 3rd prop in there but u can ignore this. Would it still work?

Comment: It may not matter, but note that you are creating **a lot** of Arrays with this code, and thus a lot of trash that GC will have to collect at some point. May be ok with a limited set of data, but if this code as to be used on big-data, and at high frequency, that may be a problem.

Comment: Of course these Arrays are created, what are you saying? They may be easy to mark as unused afterward, but they definitely exist and take place in the memory => they'll have to get GCed.

Comment: At least v8 as implemented in Chrome 73. I just tried running your code in an rAF loop against 10000 items and GC fires almost every frame. Same setup using the for in loop and GC never fired.

Comment: Juat one more question: what does it look like when the amounts are stringformat?

Comment: Sorry to update the question: i actualy noticed the amounts are in stringformat?

Comment: So what's your criteria? Sum all the keys that have "amount" as the prefix?

Comment: Updated the answer to deal with quoted numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

- Use the `reduce()` method on the array `items`
- Set the accumulator(`ac`) as an empty object i.e `{}`
- During each iteration through the objects create a `for..in` loop to iterate through all keys of object.
- Check if the `typeof` value of `key` is `"number"` then add it otherwise don't

```js
const items = [{amount1:100, amount2:50, name:"ruud"}, {amount1:40,amount2:60,name:"ted"}]

let res = [items.reduce((ac,x) => {
  for(let key in x){
    if(typeof x[key] === "number"){
      if(!ac[key]) ac[key] = 0;
      ac[key] += x[key]
    }
  }
  return ac;

},{})]
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Sorry Maheer the question has slightly changed would it still work?

Answer (score 0):

`reduce()` is indeed the way to go, but the cleanest to go only through a set of known keys is probably to pass your expected result as the accumulator and to iterate over this accumulator's keys:

```js
const items = [
  { amount1: "100", amount2: "50", name: "ruud", foo: "unrelated" },
  { amount1: "40", amount2: "60", name: "ted", foo: "0" }
];

const result = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  for (let key in acc) { // iterate over the accumulator's keys
    acc[key] += isNaN(item[key]) ? 0 : +item[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, { // here we define the expected format
  amount1: 0,
  amount2: 0
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [{amount1: 100, amount2: 50}, {amount1: 40, amount2: 60}];
function sum(data){
 const keys =  Object.keys(data[0])
 let res = {}
 for(key of keys)
   res[key]=data.map(x=>x[key]).reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
return res
  
}

console.log(sum(items))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative, simple, and clean solution for this.

```js
const items = [{amount1:100, amount2:50, name:"ruud"},{amount1:40,amount2:60,name:"ted"}]
let result = [{amount1:0,amount2:0}]
items.forEach(i=>{
  result[0].amount1 += i.amount1
  result[0].amount2 += i.amount2
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions are great. I included this if you don't want to use 
 Array.prototype.reduce(). This will work even if you have other properties which are not "numbers"

```
 const items = [{amount1: 100, amount2: 50, name: 'Ruud'}, {amount1: 40, amount2: 60, name: 'Ted'}];
 var result = {};

 items.forEach(function(eachItem){
    for(var prop in eachItem){
        if(typeof eachItem[prop] === "number"){
           result[prop] = result[prop] ? result[prop] + eachItem[prop] : eachItem[prop];                 
        }                
     }
 });
 result = [result];
 console.log(result);
```